# I want to make responsive Image Carousel in React JS with wider centered elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, responsive-design, carousel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nJyw.jpg)

I want to make a responsive Image Carousel in React JS with wider centered elements

I want to make the Carousel like that

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.